# <span class="text_exposed_hide">...</span> in "Post to Wall" dialog in ios app

Tags: ios, facebook

I have an iPhone app where I have integrated the facebook SDK as described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/.

Everything works fine; I can log in and post to my facebook wall using the "Feed" dialog.

However: When I try to add a long "description"-parameter to the "Feed" dialog, the following html-elements appear in the Post to Wall"-page that is displayed to the user:

```
<span class="text_exposed_hide">...</span><span class="text_exposed_show">
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgrO5.png)

It looks like the intention of these elements is to display a "show more"-link to the user, instead of displaying the whole (very long) description. But this doesn't work in the iPhone app, for some reason.

Here is the code I used to display the feed dialog:

```
params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          my_app_id, @"app_id",
          @"http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
          @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
          @"Facebook Dialogs", @"name",
          @"Reference Documentation", @"caption",
          @"This is a very long description. This is a very long description. This is a very long description. This is a very long description. This is a very long description. This is a very long description. This is a very long description. This is a very long description. This is a very long description. This is a very long description. This is a very long description. This is a very long description. ", @"description",
          @"Facebook Dialogs are so easy!",  @"message",
          nil];
[self.appDelegate.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self.appDelegate];
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix/work around this? For now, I have had to reduce the length of the description-string, so that it is short enough to not trigger the bug, but that is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

This ist a Bug in the SDK.
I found this link: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/178341818925933?browse=search_4f045d875c1b89787847645

A workaround could be to implement a JS funktion into the WebView wich is strip this tag out.

Comment: Facebook has confirmed it as a bug. See that link that you posted.